# Configurar webdriver Firefox no Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Estou usando o selenium (Python) para buscar alguns dados de um site, em um determinado momento eu acesso um link que faz o download de um arquivo. Como configuro o webdriver (Firefox) para que ele aceite automaticamente o download, sem que eu preciso clicar em baixar?

Answer (score 3):

Use [`FirefoxProfile`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html) para configurar seu Firefox antes de instanciar o *browser*:

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    import os

    firefox_profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()

    firefox_profile.set_preference("browser.download.folderList",2)
    firefox_profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",False)
    firefox_profile.set_preference("browser.download.dir", os.getcwd())
    firefox_profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/octet-stream")

    browser = Firefox(firefox_profile = firefox_profile)
```

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou perfeitamente!

Comment: [Veja aqui como o site funciona](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour). Obrigado!

Comment: Eu só queria saber se você pode me ajudar em mais um a coisa rs, o arquivo que está sendo baixado. Existe algum set_preference que eu possa renomea-lo?

Comment: Não. Você possivelmente vai ter que baixar o arquivo e depois renomear usando `os`.